# Vertical scroll buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello dear colleagues,

I'm trying to find a solution for a website that I'm building. The website is reach in texts and we are trying to give 3 actions to the users. Scroll Up, Scroll Down and Go to Top.

Also I want to represent the whole page height on a bar that will have the same height, no matter how high the content is. In another words, the height of the content will always be represented by a 80px bar and the bar button also will always have 10px height.

For the first problem I'm tyring to use window.scrollBy but it doesn't seem to be working for me. For the second problem I don't really have an ideia yet and I would appreciate any help to put me on the right direction.

Here is my current code and also bellow I'm attaching my Jsfiddle.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <p>header</p>
</div>
<div id="docnav">
    <button onclick="scrollUp()">Up</button>
    <div id="sidescroll">
        <div id="sidescrollbtn"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="scrollDown()">Down</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="scrollTop()">Go to Top</button><br><br>
</div>
<div id="maincontent">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header{width:100%;background:red;height:100px;}
#docnav{position:fixed;right:0,width:10%;background:red;right:8px;text-align:center;}
#sidescroll{height:80px;width:10px;background:grey;border:1px solid black;margin:0 auto;}
#sidescrollbtn{height:10px;width:10px;background:red;margin-top:10px;}
#maincontent{border:1px solid black;background-color:lightblue;height:1000px;width:500px;margin:0 0 100px 20px;}
#footer{height:100px;width:100%;background:red;position:fixed;bottom:0;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function scrollUp()
{
   window.scrollBy(0,20);
}

function scrollDown()
{
   window.scrollBy(0,-20);
}

function scrollTop()
{
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/bruetck6/3/

Comment: Regarding the `window.scrollBy`, it does work. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/bruetck6/5/ (tested in Chrome, if it's not working, it may be a browser issue?) I updated your fiddle to load the scripts appropriately. I also reversed the offsets (since clicking "up" was scrolling down)

Comment: Clicking `Go to top` does nothing because you're offsetting by 0. In addition, it throws an error because it's attempting to call the `window` method `scrollTop`, which returns a number (the scrollTop). Rather than call scrollBy, you'll want to set the offset explicitly.

Comment: If you're open to using jQuery, here's an updated fiddle that includes jQuery helper methods: http://jsfiddle.net/bruetck6/8/

Comment: As for your second problem, you'll need to get the height of your page document and height of your viewport. You'll need to calculate the ratio between the document height and the gray div - then adjust the height of the red div for your viewport. Hopefully that helps you solving the issue :)

Comment: Hi Jack, Thank you for your time. Jquery can definitely be considered  and I was wondering if there is a function that keep scrolling while I keep the button pressed. As for the second problem your logic is good, but I don't intend to re-size the red square and so I would change it's margin top instead of it's height.

Comment: Hi Vinicius. To simulate continuous scrolling, you need to set flags for when a user `mousedown` and `mouseup`. On `mousedown`, you set an interval and click continuously, until the `mouseup` event is triggered. Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/bruetck6/12/

Comment: Nice Jack. This is beautiful!!

Comment: I noticed a little bug on this solution. If I have the mousedown on the button up or down and move the mouse off the button the script behaves badly. Any ideas on this? I'm working on that initial idea for the second problem. http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/2y63xnxa/2/

Comment: Ah, good point! There are two ways to address this. The easy way is to add an event listener for `mouseleave` http://jsfiddle.net/2y63xnxa/18/ - The other way is to bind an event listener on the document body and delegate the mouse events to it. The advantage to the second way is that as long as the user is clicking "down", you will continue scrolling (similar to how many apps behave these days...)